# Checkbox multiplos e salvar no banco

Tags: php, html, mysql, checkbox

Tenho um formulário no qual eu vou poder marcar vários `checkbox` ao mesmo tempo e queria saber como que eu identifico os que estão marcados e salvá-los no banco de dados.

No banco eu vou ter uma tabela e uma coluna para cada `checkbox` porque isto é um cadastro de uma consulta, e se a pessoa for fazer vários tratamentos, os que estiverem marcados vai dar um `OK` naquela coluna no banco de dados.

Por exemplo se a pessoa for fazer tratamento de **Reiki** e de **Acupuntura**, vai aparecer um `OK` em Reiki e um `OK` em Acupuntura.

```html
<form name="signup" method="post" action="../cadastro_con.php">
  <div>
  
  <form name="signup" method="post" action="cadastrar.php">
  <div align="center">
    <table width="800" border="1" bordercolor="#B9B3B3" cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><p><br>
            NOME:
            <input type="text" name="nomec" size=50/>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;DATA DA CONSULTA:
            <input name="data" type="date" />
            <br>
          </p>
            <table width="600" border="0" bordercolor="#B9B3B3" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td width="185" height="86" align="center" bordercolor="#FFFFFF" bgcolor="#DDF0DD" style="border-style:none" >TRATAMENTOS A SEREM REALIZADOS</td>
                  <td width="256"  style="border-right-style:none">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="db">
                  <label>Desobsessao e Desmaterializa&ccedil;&atilde;o
                  </label><br>
                  <label>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="cr">
                      Cirurgias </label><br>
                      <label>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="rk">
                      Reiki
                    </label></td>
                      
                  <td width="114" style="border-left-style:none">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="crm">
                    <label >Cromoterapia
                    </label><br>
                    <label>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="acp">
                      Acupuntura
                      <br>
                     </label>
                     <label>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="pdc">
                      Passe de Cura
                    </label></td>
                  </tr>
              </tbody>
        </table>
            </form>
```

Não coloquei o código todo, mas depois disso se eu clicar em cadastrar, ele chama a página que irá inserir os dados no banco. Vai haver uma coluna para cada opção e se ela estiver marcada, irá armazenar um `OK`.

Se alguém souber como fazer isso e puder-me ajudar, agradeço.

Comment: Qual é o problema? não seria melhor guardar os checkbox em uma tabela a parte? ex, consulta e itens_consulta ?

Comment: eu preciso salvar o que a pessoa vai fazer de tratamento pois depois eu vou mostrar esses dados nos relatorio geral e ainda tem os dias de presença. cada dia da semana é um tratamento intao quem tiver fazendo reiki eu vou listar as pessoas em reiki.

Comment: Coloca a estrutura da tabela

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para fazer isto, só tens de atribuir índices a esses(as) array, ainda no formulário *HTML*.

```
<div class="info"><?php echo isset($msg) ? "<h2>Retorno:</h2>" . $msg . "<hr>" : NULL; ?></div>
        <h2>Formulário:</h2>
        <form method="POST" action="">
            <input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Digite o seu nome"/><br/><br/>
            <h3>Trabalhou como:</h3>
            <label for="check[med]">Médico(a):
            <input type="checkbox" name="check[med]" value="Médico(a)"/>
            </label><br/>
            <label for="check[mec]"> Mecânico:
                <input type="checkbox" name="check[mec]" value="Mecânico(a)"/>
            </label><br/><br/>
            <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar"/>
        </form>
```

E com o *PHP* bastava que lesses os valores neles contidos.

```
if(isset($_POST["enviar"])){
    $nome = isset($_POST["nome"]) ? (string) $_POST["nome"] : NULL;
    $prof = isset($_POST["check"]) ? $_POST["check"] : NULL;
    if(!empty($prof) && !empty($nome)){ 
        $msg = null;
        $msg .= "<b>Nome:</b> " . $nome . "<br/>";
        $msg .= "<b>Já trabalhou como: </b><br/>";  
        foreach($prof as $val){ 
            $msg .= $val . "<br/>";
        }   
    }   
}
```

Este exemplo é simples e fácil de testar. Se continuares com algumas dúvidas faça algumas modificações no *HTML* e usa o `print_r($_POST)` para ver quais valores foram enviados, e como estão identificados ou organizados nessa array.

Answer (score 0):

Para esse caso, o uso de operadores BIT a BIT caem como uma Luva.
Para isso é importante entender o conceito.

Um exemplo em código.
Supondo que eu tenha 4 opções que podem ser selecionadas individualmente ou simultaneamente: estudante, empregado, eleitor, deficiente
Eu atribuo a cada um, valor potência de 2 iniciando em 0

```
estudante = 2^0 = 1
empregado = 2^1 = 2
eleitor = 2^2 = 4
deficiente = 2^3 = 8
```

Para atribuir qualquer um deles basta somá-lo ao total
Ex.: Para atribuir empregado, eleitor e deficiente eu somo 2+4+8 = 14
No momento de exibir as opções marcadas eu uso o operador & (E Comercial ou Ampersand) para saber se a opção está contida no total

```
    2 & 14 == 2 // Se o resultado da operação for o próprio valor ele está contido
    1 & 14 == 1 // Nesse caso, como 1 não está contido no total, o resultado será 0
```

Assim, basta adaptar essa regra a sua necessidade.

Se desejar apenas recuperar uma informação do HTML e salvar no banco de dados use a forma comum mesmo.

```
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="depilacao" />
```

No PHP vai recuperar pelo atributo NAME

```
    $depilacao = isset($_REQUEST['depilacao']) ? (int) $_REQUEST['depilacao'] : null;
    // ...
    if ($depilacao > 0 ) // Marcou a opção depilação
```

Só esclarecendo o comentário que disse que teria muitas condições usando operador BIT a BIT: 
Da forma como expus, voce pode ter quantas opções quiser que um código simples resolverá, bastando para isso salvar a soma em um unico campo no banco de dados e ter uma tabela apenas com os serviços que quer que apareça como opção.
Ter uma coluna para cada serviço é a forma errada de fazer.

Comment: eu preciso sabe capturar o checkbox e salvar no banco isso q vc fez eu teria q montar dezenas de condições e axo q n é isso ai nao. eu so quero pega o q ta marcado e da um ok na respectiva coluna no banco.

Comment: Para o seu HTML seria algo como

`$todos = isset($_REQUEST['check']) ? (array) $_REQUEST['check'] ? array();`

`if (isset($todos['kr'])) { // marcou Reiki `

Comment: olha é assim. eu vou cadastrar a data da consulta da pessoa. todos os tratamentos q ela form salvar eu tenho que salvar noa banco. no banco vai ter uma tabela com varias colunas pq cada cadastro tera um id. pegar a quantidade de opçoes marcadas nao serve. pq eu preciso marcar no banco na coluna de reiki se ela vai fazer ou nao, na coluna de acupuntura se vai fazer ou nao.

Comment: Sim, o que passei no comentário é o que precisa fazer.
No seu HTML voce esta usando o mesmo name para todos os campos checkbox adicionado de [] o que fará o PHP converter para um array onde cada índice será o nome do campo.

Comment: intao é q pra monta eu entendi q tinha q fazer como array mas ate agora nao entendi como q eu capturo os marcados e salvo no lugar certinho no banco e suas mensagens eu vi depois q eu respondi

Comment: quando um campo é marcado, ele é enviado na forma de **nome=valor** para a página
Como seus campos possuem todos os mesmos names (check[]) ele será enviado como **check[]=valor**. No PHP, tens de verificar se ele foi ou não marcado assim: `$rk = isset($_REQUEST['chek']['rk']);`
Se $rk for diferente de falso é porque ele foi marcado e então tem que continuar a escrever o código para marcar o campo do Banco.

Comment: consegui aki valeu

Comment: @MarcosRegis como poderia resolver esse meu http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/178626/como-usar-o-implode-array-to-string